# Android eclipse edittext input calculated result shown on another empty edittext(automatically)

Tags: android, eclipse

i am making an application to calculate PMT fucntion, but i got stuck on calculating the 1st payment. short explanation :
my apps will have 3 edittexts, 1 for price ,1 for percentage and last one for the result of them, for example we input the price  100.000 then the 1st payment 30
then the 3rd one will automatically shows the result in this case its 30.000

```
Edittext1:
100000
Edittext2:
30
Edittext3:
30000(this one automatically calculate when we done give an input in the Edittext2)
```

this is the code:

```
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String text1 = editText1.getText().toString();
            if (text1.length() != 0) {
                int input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);

                int input2 = Integer.valueOf(s.toString());

                int output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                editText3.setText(output + "");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Number to decimal converter

```
public void makeDecimal(View v)
                {
                                ethint1.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

                                DigitsKeyListener dkl = new DigitsKeyListener(true,true);
                                ethint1.setKeyListener(dkl);

                                ethint1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                        private String current = "";

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                String userInput=s.toString();

                                if(!userInput.toString().equals(current)){
                                                ethint1.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                                                String cleanString = userInput.replaceAll("[,]", "");

                                                if(cleanString.length()>0){
                                                                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);                                                
                                                                String formated = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance().format(parsed);

                                                                current = formated;
                                                                ethint1.setText(formated);
                                                                ethint1.setSelection(formated.length());
                                                }else{
                                                                ethint1.setText(cleanString);
                                                                ethint1.setSelection(cleanString.length());
                                                }

                                                ethint1.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                int count, int after) {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                int before, int count) {
                        }
                    });                                                           
               }
```

ethint1 = edittext1 i changed some variables

the logcat:::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '1,000,000' as integer
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:433)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:422)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:682)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.Mastercode$1.onTextChanged(Mastercode.java:43)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6172)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6316)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:174)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:247)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:73)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Question Updated::
is there a way to make both works(number converter and that 3rd edittext output)
.Note:for number converter, i actually want to make it shown as a currency
when we input the numbers into edittext1(ethint1) it will automatically add a separator .EXAMPLE: we type 100 it will just be 100(nothing changed) then when we put one more number it will be 1,000(automatically) and so on until 10,000,000,000

/*there is no error on error log/ problems but will crash when we input the percentage*/

thanks in advance,

Comment: Restart your eclipse and post the LogCat

Comment: `but will crash when we input the percentage` means getting crash log in logcat

Comment: found it clashing with a function which will convert the 1st edittext input to decimal, a sec, i ll update both logcat and that function code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
editText3.setText(output + "");
```

to

```
editText3.setText("" + output);
```

**Explanation:**
`output` is an integer value while `.setText()` takes a String argument. Adding `""` (blank string) before any integer will convert it into (let Java believe that it is) String.

Comment: the problem is not that,i have updated the problem..
BTW this is a good idea , i got that

Comment: @georgesamuel Where are you calling makeDecimal()? I am not getting the point, but as far as I understand your problem is about parsing "10,000" (Strings with commas) into int. If that is so, then NO, you can't parse it into int. Just remove the commas from the string wherever you have to parse it into int and add them again when you are showing them to user.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
editText3.setText(output + "");
```

to

```
editText3.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```